# How to detect all the time added class?

Tags: javascript, lazy-loading

I have a carousel gallery with lazy loading images (it uses lazysizes script). Every image has its own container, to that is adding a class when the image is loaded. The problem I am struggling with is that this class is added only to the first gallery item, but I want to add this class to the all containers, when the images are loaded.

When the image is loaded then the **lazyloaded** class is added to it. Now, thanks to **lazyFeaturedImage** function I'm able to detect the **lazyloaded** class and add to the image container (**.hero__image**) a **.hero__image--overlay** class.

All works fine but only for the first gallery item, in others, the **.hero__image--overlay** class is not added.

```
<div class="hero__image hero__image--overlay">
   <img class="hero__image-img lazyloaded"  src="1.png"  alt="{{alt}}">
</div>

<div class="hero__image">
   <img class="hero__image-img lazyloaded"  src="2.png"  alt="{{alt}}">
</div>


var lazyFeaturedImage = function lazyFeaturedImage() {
   var lazyFeaturedImageImg = document.querySelector('.hero__image-img');
       lazyFeaturedImageImg.addEventListener('lazyloaded', function (e)  {
           var featuredImage = document.querySelector(".hero__image");
               featuredImage.classList.add('hero__image--overlay');
  });
}
lazyFeaturedImage();
```

I will be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Is your second picture rendered (`<img class="hero__image-img">`) at the time, when the function is executed? It seems like it is not, then your second image just is not found by `document.querySelector('.hero__image-img')` and not processed.

Comment: Its not, the lazy load script loads the next images wih delay.

Comment: Then the problem is that your function dont see the second image, because function is executed before the html is created, then you should detect the exact moment of picture start loading and then apply the function or something like this

Comment: Is there any solution for that?

Comment: You should apply this function every time new image is rendered